# C# .NET Core - Factory method vs Constructor

Tags: c#, testing, .net-core, constructor, factory-pattern

I have a class with a constructor that only sets the private attributes. This class is used in many automated tests and I need to add another private attribute. What is a good approach to avoid updating the instances of the class in the test methods?
Should I overload the constructor or use factory pattern?

I thought when the new private attribute is not important in test cases such as adding an ILogger then I can overload the constructor but if the private attribute is required in test cases, then I better use the factory method.
What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You really want to stick with dependency injection through the constructor for all dependencies, such as ILogger or whatnot. That way you can utilize ASP.NET Core dependency injection correctly.

For dependencies you do not want to use in a unit test scenario, you probably want to mock it away using [MOQ](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/), [Fake It Easy](https://fakeiteasy.github.io/) or similar frameworks.

That way, you know for sure that once your class is created, the ILogger etc will exist and may not be null sometimes and set other times.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "stick with dependency injection through the constructor for all dependencies". Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand it; so I am sharing in case it helps others.

Factory pattern is about creating s.th, hence the name Factory. If a constructor becomes complicated, or internal methods are involved in creating an instance of a class (i.e. object), this is an indication of using a factory method.

e.g. You want to localize the logic to instantiate a complex object

If you have a FooFactory class, this class creates an instance of Foo, and encapsulates the details of implementations.

So a constructor that only configures the dependency injections should not use Factory pattern.